# Objective C syntax?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

In Objective C if given that X is an Integer what does is `! X` Does it mean a user logical negation operator like Java, or if it has value `0` then X is non zero?

Answer (score 1):

Operator `!` in Objective-C is the same as in C. It is a logical *not* operator, which operates on numbers.

- When the input number is zero, the result is `1`
- When the input is non-zero, the result is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is a strict superset of the "C" language so it behaves exactly the same as "C" (which it is). `!` is the logical not operator.

```
int x = 3;
int y = ! x;
int z = ! y;
```

> x: 3
>   y: 0
>   z: 1